# How do I one element align to the left, and another align to the right?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my `Windows Phone 7` app, I would like to have a `TextBlock` followed by a `CheckBox`. From left to right.

I am doing this **programmatically**, and I can do this with the following code:

```
StackPanel ControlStackPanel = new StackPanel();
ControlStackPanel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;

TextBlock ControlTextBlock = new TextBlock();
ControlTextBlock.Text = @"ControlNameGoesHere";

CheckBox ControlCheckBox = new CheckBox();
ControlCheckBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
ControlCheckBox.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;

ControlStackPanel.Children.Add(ControlTextBlock);
ControlStackPanel.Children.Add(ControlCheckBox);
```

However, **I would actually like the `TextBlock` element to align to the *left* side of the screen, and the `CheckBox` element align to the *right* side of the screen. How can I do this?**

Do I need to add a grid programmatically? The reason I don't want to do this in XAML is that adding these stackpanels is going to be an iterative process, and it just works better with my code if I do it all programmatically.

I've googled a heck of a lot, but haven't had much luck.

Many thanks!
Brett

Answer (score 0):

A content control only has one alignment at once.  All the controls within it are aligned according to it's horizontal alignment.  You may wish to have two content controls with the different alignments inside a larger outer container.

```
Grid
  StackPanel left
     Control
  StackPanel right
     Control
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your controls into columns of Grid. ControlTextBox should go to the first column of the Grid, ControlCheckBox - into the second one.
Here's some code:

```
TextBlock ControlTextBlock = new TextBlock();
ControlTextBlock.Text = @"ControlNameGoesHere";
ControlTextBlock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
ControlTextBlock.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;

CheckBox ControlCheckBox = new CheckBox();
ControlCheckBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
ControlCheckBox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
ControlCheckBox.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;

ColumnDefinition FirstColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
FirstColumn.Width = System.Windows.GridLength.Auto;
ColumnDefinition SecondColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
SecondColumn.Width = System.Windows.GridLength.Auto;

Grid ContentGrid = new Grid();
ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(FirstColumn);
ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(SecondColumn);
ContentGrid.Children.Add(ControlTextBlock);
ContentGrid.Children.Add(ControlCheckBox);
```